# Best way to check if an email exists

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I developped an application java using spring-boot framework. In my class, before saving the user I need to check if his email exists in a list of 1000 emails, if the check is ok I have to set a boolean that the user is a loyel user.

My question is what is the best implementation for checking that if the user email exist in that list or not in short time:

```
1- Read a file that contain the 1000 emails each time when a user will be created. What is the best way to do that without read every time the file ?
using a singleton....
 2- Create an email ArrayList and parse it each time ???
 3. create a database and make a request to check each time if the email exists
```

Would you have any suggestion ?

Best regards

Comment: what do you mean when say 'the best way'? The best with perfomance? Mainentantability? Your teachers degree? Less code?

Comment: I mean performance and speed

Comment: please clarify. Speed of what? Do you intend to use clasters? Are you sure there will be exactly 1,000 e-mails and never 1,001?

Comment: I have a fixed list of 1000 emails. When a user ask the API createUser, I need to check if  his email in that list or not. If the check is ok I will set a boolean that his is an old user of my company. My question is what is the speedest implementation, in terme of time, to get that boolean (exist or not).

Answer (score -1):

It depends. Don't hope you find right solution at the first time. Just write it down and go next. If you met some issues the return and re-write. It's usual practice in programming

The main thing you could do right at this moment is develop kind of contract (or interface) which will not change from time to time. Simplest contract would be `Collection<String> getCorrectEmails()`. Possibly `Iterable<String> getCorrectEmails()` will be better since you could implement it with streams/Databases/microservice/whatever

---

**UPDATED**
Since you have only 1,000 of e-mails which is possibly do not change you could hard-code them. To avoid source code inflating I suggest introduce a holder in another file:

```
class ValidEmailHolder {
   // note method is non-static. It WILL help you in the future
   /* use Collection instead List isn't necessary but a good practice 
   to return more broad interface when you assume it could be changed in next 10 years */
   public Collection<String> getEmails() {
      return EMAILS;
   }

   private static final List<String> EMAILS = Arrays.asList(
      "email1@domain",
      "email2@domain",
     // many lines here
      "email1000@domain"
      );
}
```

and then use it in your class

```
public Collection<String> getValidEmails() { 
  ValidEmailHolder.getEmails();
}
```

note I just call ValidEmailHolder.getEmails() inside method. This is a [Bridge pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern) and here it'll help you if you want to change behavior. Most likely you'll want to introduce list of e-mails in external file, maybe in a DB or even in system properties. Then you could write down `ValidEmailFileHolder` and then simply change call. Also you could add logic like this

```
Collection<String> result = ValidEmailDbHolder.getEmails();
if (result == null || result.isEmpty()) {
  result = ValidEmailHolder.getEmails();
}
return result;
```

But possibly you don't need this. The point you could do it easily

Comment: Thanks @ADS But what the speedest solution that I will implement inside of checkIfEmailExist.

Comment: speedest solution is write down `getCorrectEmails(){//TODO}`.

Comment: Unless you know ho often it could be changed and who will it change you don't know what you need. It's OK since many things you will know after run prototype for a week. You **definetely will rewrite this method** so don't care about it right now